# Automatically add/interpret trailing slashes for items in public/ directory?

Tags: meteor

Quick question about Meteor's public directory and static `index.html` files:

My app has a few static pages. Rather than set up a whole routing thing, I've just dropped them in subdirectories of public/. Overall it works pretty well: if I have an HTML file at `<app root>/public/somedir/index.html` then navigating to `http://my-app.com/somedir/` will produce that page. But **if I leave off the trailing slash,** it doesn't work: I just end up back at the root of my app as though I'd simply navigated to `http://my-app.com/`.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to do this in Meteor yet.

It is possible to do it yourself, *if* you have detailed knowledge of Meteor's internals *and* you know how to write [express](http://expressjs.com/) middleware :-)  See the appcache package source for an example (it intercepts calls to the "/app.manifest" URL and generates its own response).

But personally, I'd just take the plunge and set up routes.  Meteor is designed as a single web page framework, and it's going to be easier to develop your application using that model rather than fighting it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There seem to be multiple resources for setting up routes in Meteor...is there a most "standard" or well-established approach?

Comment: I haven't made a survey of the options, but routing is not hard to implement -- it's simply displaying or not displaying particular templates based on the URL.  So I'd choose a route package that had an API that I liked.